# Null pointer exception in arraycopy

Tags: java, arrays, generics, nullpointerexception

I am currently learning Java and am trying to work through learning generics. I have the class `Holder` which takes varargs. I am trying to place these into an array `myArray` for future use. However I get a `NullPointerException` on the arraycopy line and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
class Holder<T> {

  T[] myArray;

  public Holder(T... args) {
    System.arraycopy(args, 0, myArray, 0, args.length);  //null pointer exception
  }
```

This is what I am using to create the instance:

```
Holder<Integer> mySample = new Holder<>(1,2,3);
```

Comment: `myArray` is not initialised (it is `null`)

Comment: Add a breakpoint at this line and see which of (`args` or `myArray` is null).

Comment: Pro tip: You can [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) arrays, so you could ditch that complicated arraycopy call and just say `myArray = args.clone();`

Comment: myArray = args.clone() fixed it. Just curious how would I initialise myArray without getting a "generic array creation" error?

Answer (score 3):

it is because `myarray` is not initialized.

```
T[] myArray; // `myarray` is uninitialized, as of now.

public Holder(T... args) {
    if(args != null && args.length > 0) {
        myArray = new t[args.length]; // `myarray` is initialized here.
        System.arraycopy(args, 0, myArray, 0, args.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a `null` and `0` length check of `args` and you have yourself a nice answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer 0 length array shouldn't cause any problem

Comment: No, but why waste a call to `arrayCopy` :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer why null check? This code _should_ break if you pass it `null` instead of a proper array. If you let `myArray` be null you're just deferring the problem to a later occasion, which makes it harder to find the error.

Comment: Generally, checking for `null` is good practice.  `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception, meaning it won't be caught by normal `try-catch` blocks. Better to simply allow the `myArray` to remain `null` (which matches the requirements of the method) then crash the program - IMHO.  Programming by exception is never a good idea ;)

Comment: when I try initialising the array like in the above example I get an error:

Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class t

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.arraycopy(args, 0, myArray, 0, args.length);
```

1)`myArray` is not `intialized` .

2)and possibility of  `args` to be `null`